# Received sun.net.www.protocol.http.httpurlconnection$httpinputstream as response while calling service which is unable to process

Tags: soap, apache-camel, cxf, jbossfuse, cxf-client

I'm developing workflow application in Apache camel

Business Use case:

1. Service is exposed at consumer endpoint
2. Processing with request message
3. Call external SOAP Service, get the response
4. check particular tag in response xml and then only call another external SOAP Service
5. Return the final response to client

Now I got stuck in step 4

My camel Route is

```
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">

    <route streamCache="true">
      <from uri="cxf:bean:proxyEndpoint"/>
        <process ref="myProcessor"/>
             <!-- processing request & logging -->
      <setBody>
             <!-- set request as body required for calling external web service -->
      </setBody>
      <to uri="cxf:bean:panEndpoint"/>
      <!-- <to uri="file:C:/LOG" /> -->
      <!--  <process ref="myProcessor2"/> -->
      <log message="&gt;&gt;&gt; ${body}" loggingLevel="INFO"/> 

    </route>
  </camelContext>
```

I'm able to call external Service but after `<to uri="cxf:bean:panEndpoint"/>` if I try to log body I'm getting arbitrary value same in case of routing to file.

When I tried to route to Processor and print `System.out.println(exchange.getIn().getBody());`
I'm getting `sun.net.www.protocol.http.httpurlconnection$httpinputstream` which I'm unable to parse or process

External Service is called and proper response is receiving as I tried to monitor the scenario using TCP-IP Monitor

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Tell Camel what type you want the body as, and it uses its type converter to make that happen (if possible).

So if you want the body as a `InputStream` do

```
exchange.getIn().getBody(InputStream.class)
```

If you want it as String, then do

```
exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class)
```

Read more here

- http://camel.apache.org/type-converter.html

And when working with streams mind about stream caching

- http://camel.apache.org/stream-caching.html

Comment: I was debugging the application and so I did System.out.println(exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class)); But as I said earlier it is giving me arbitrary value see like this : @????{???{???;?N'????\fd☺l??J??!???▼?~|▼?"▲?▲?▬ez??MQ-??hw??Q?/??X^|??=?>???8z?T?????2/?U??+??◄>??y?▲??L??"k??§>▼W??]?r7??~???k
Any other suggestion ?